# Data isn't passed to api call

Tags: javascript, php, angularjs, codeigniter

I'm working on one project with AngularJs(1.5) and Codeigniter rest server. I'm wondering why data idTag isn't passed to php? Let me show you my code and explain further with comments.

I have this factory

```
factory.get = function(idLocation, idTag){
    console.log(idLocation, idTag); //Console log outputs 1 6, so data is here

    return $http({
        method: 'GET',
        url: $location.protocol() + '://' + $location.host() + '/rest/api/locationtag/locationtag/' + idLocation,
        data: {
            idTag: idTag
        }
    }).then(function successCallback(response){
        console.log(response);
        // response is empty, because data isn't sent to PHP
        return response.data;
    },function errorCallback(response){
        console.log('Error getting slide shows: ' + response.data.message);
    });
};
```

And this is my PHP where i try to fetch the code

```
public function locationtag_get($idLocation)
{
    $condition['id_location'] = $idLocation;
    $condition['id_tag'] = $this->get('idTag');
    var_dump($condition);
    die();
    $locationTag = $this->locations_tags->get($condition);
    if ($locationTag) {
        $this->response($locationTag, REST_Controller::HTTP_OK);
    }
}
```

Out put of var_dump is

```
 'id_location' '1'
 'id_tag' null
```

SO the question, why or how to properly send data from GET method to PHP rest controller in Codeigniter?

If you need any additional information's, please let me know and i will provide. Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For GET requests you should use `params` instead of `data` (which is for POST requests). You can confirm this in the AngularJS [documentation](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$http#usage).

> params – {Object.} – Map of strings or objects which
>   will be serialized with the paramSerializer and appended as GET
>   parameters.

Of course, nothing stops you from adding them to the URL but you'd have to deal with encoding the information properly instead of just passing the JSON object.

Answer (score 1):

You should be using a `params` property in your $http config object:

```
$http({
    url: $location.protocol() + '://' + $location.host() + '/rest/api/locationtag/locationtag/' + idLocation,
        data: {, 
    method: "GET",
    params: {idTag: idTag}
 });
```

This will append as query string to you url, which you can then inspect in your server side code.